# Exclude a year from MYSQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table - Client which stores name and birthday.  Where we don't have the year of birth, this defaults to 1920, because I thought this would be easy to exclude from a MYSQL query.

I can work out the age:

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - 
          DATE_FORMAT(Birthday, '%Y') -
          (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < 
          DATE_FORMAT(Birthday, '00-%m-%d')) AS age FROM Client
```

**But can not get it to ignore anyone born in 1920.**

I've tried `WHERE YEAR>1920 and WHERE YEAR(Birthday) > 1920`, putting back ties and quotes etc and `WHERE age < 90` but cannot get this to work.

(I got the way to work the out their ages from another answer on StackOverflow btw).

Comment: What _type_ is the Birthday column?

Comment: Birthday is Date.

Just tried SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(Birthday, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(Birthday, '00-%m-%d'))WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Birthday)>1920 AS age FROM Client

Which didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

**where EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Birthday)>1920**

Answer (score 0):

I have got it to work by putting the EXTRACT at the end of the query :

```
SELECT *, 
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') -
DATE_FORMAT(Birthday, '%Y') - 
(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(Birthday, '00-%m-%d'))
AS age 
FROM Client 
WHERE (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Birthday))>1920
```

Thanks for your help - it got me on the right path.